# I'm encountering this error after importing projects using Libgdx

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx

Whats going on here? Why am I getting this Error?!

this is the error..

Cannot find System Java Compiler. Ensure that you have installed a JDK (not just a JRE) and configured your JAVA_HOME system variable to point to the according directory.
Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-all.zip'.

Comment: Have you tried adding java_home as a system variable and pointing it to the jdk?

Comment: I will just ask the obvious (since you don't mention anything and I have seen alot on SO).Have you installed the JDK?

Comment: I have. Sorry for not mentioning. But I did manage to fix it. Don't know why but I restarted and it went away.

Comment: @JenniferHall ,yea eclipse is doing things like that, also a usual one is to be missing the Object class file witch also is getting fixed with just a restart.In future problems like that just do 1) refresh  the project 2)clean the project 3)restart eclipse